# CASE plus WAIT statements

Tags: vhdl

I'm developing a simulation model of a component that I need in my design.
To make it fast and simple I decided to only create it in a behavioral manner (eg not synthesizable).

To do so I'm using a CASE statement (representing an FSM) with WAIT statements inside.

```
main : PROCESS
BEGIN 
    CASE state IS
         WHEN S0 =>
            WAIT UNTIL start = '1';
            state <= S1;

         WHEN S1 =>
            WAIT UNTIL stop = '1';
            state <= S2;

         WHEN S2 =>

            ...

         WHEN OTHERS =>
    END CASE;
END PROCESS;
```

The problem is that state enters `S1` when the `start`signal is asserted but doesn't enter `S2`when `stop`is asserted.

I always thought that using a WAIT statement in a CASE stucked the process in a given state until the condition is valid but this example shows that I'm wrong. What do you guys think of this?

Comment: what is the value of `stop` *before* entering the state? `wait` is waiting for change *and* the condition.

Comment: `start`and `stop`are both low first. That's why I can't get why it doesn't work (I tried with `rising_edge` too...)

Comment: As written it'll enter S1 then the process will end. Perhaps you meant to loop around the CASE statement?

Comment: It actually loops around the CASE, but too fast. I needed some temporization at the end of the process to get the right behavior. Thank you for your advices.

Answer (score 1):

Well ...I finally found the issue.

For those who could also wonder why this isn't working, in fact you just need a WAIT statement at the end of the process (outside the CASE statement).

The thing is, when `start` goes high, `state` is actually updated and take its new value: S1. Yet, since I'm not using any sensitivity list, the process is running indefinitely and at the same time that `state` is updated, the process comes back into S0 waiting for another `start` signal ...

That's why you just need this at the end:

```
    ...
    END CASE
WAIT FOR time_value;
END PROCESS;
```

Comment: The problem is that signal assignment does not occur until the end of the time interval.  So, your `wait until ...` statement waits.  When the event occurs, then you assign the signal.  But time has not yet advanced, so `state` is still at its previous value.  The process restarts, and `state` is still S0, so it waits again.  I'll elaborate in an answer.

Answer (score 1):

First, some preliminaries.

The `wait` statement waits for an event **and** the condition to be true.  So, if there is no event, the condition will not be evaluated.  So, if `start` is already 1 when entering S0, it will halt on the `wait` statement until `start` changes **and** becomes 1.

Also, as I noted in my comment, signal assignment does not occur until the end of the time step.  Signal assignments are **non-blocking**.  That is, the assignment does not block execution until the assignment is complete.  As you have it written, it will take 2 changes on `start` going to 1 to cause a transition to state S1.  I tweaked your code to add some report statements, and put it into a testbench.  Here's the code:

```
main : PROCESS
BEGIN
  while true loop
    CASE state IS
         WHEN S0 =>
            report "Entering S0, waiting for start";
            WAIT UNTIL start = '1';
            state <= S1;

         WHEN S1 =>
            report "Entering S1, waiting for stop";
            WAIT UNTIL stop = '1';
            state <= S2;

         WHEN OTHERS =>
    END CASE;
  end loop;
END PROCESS;
```

Now, the testbench just pulses `start` twice (using 1 ps wide pulses, so '0' at time 0, '1' at time 1 ps, '0' at time 2 ps, and '1' at time 3 ps).  Watch what happens:

```
VSIM 1> run 5 ps
# ** Note: Entering S0, waiting for start
#    Time: 0 ps  Iteration: 0  Instance: /foo
# ** Note: Entering S0, waiting for start
#    Time: 1 ps  Iteration: 1  Instance: /foo
# ** Note: Entering S1, waiting for stop
#    Time: 3 ps  Iteration: 1  Instance: /foo
```

See the transition to S1?  This is because your code is doing this.

- Assume a starting state of S0
- Wait for `start` to change **and** become 1
- Schedule `state` to go to S1.  Note state is not yet S1.  The **non-blocking** assignment allows execution to continue before the assignment is complete.
- Restart the process.
- State is still S0 (the scheduled update to `state` hasn't occurred yet).
- Wait for `start` to change **and** become 1.  This completes the time interval and now `state` changes to S1.
- Schedule `state` to go to S1.  It is already S1.
- Restart the process.
- State is now S1.  Wait for `stop` to change **and** become 1.  This complete the time interval and now `state` changes (again) to S1.

So, there's two ways to fix it.  The first is to assign `state` *before* waiting for the signal to change.  For example:

```
main : PROCESS
BEGIN
  while true loop
    CASE state IS
         WHEN S0 =>
            report "Entering S0, waiting for start";
            state <= S1;
            WAIT UNTIL start = '1';

         WHEN S1 =>
            report "Entering S1, waiting for stop";
            state <= S2;
            WAIT UNTIL stop = '1';

         WHEN OTHERS =>
    END CASE;
  end loop;
END PROCESS;
```

Now, look what happens with the same stimulus on `start`:

```
VSIM 1> run 5 ps
# ** Note: Entering S0, waiting for start
#    Time: 0 ps  Iteration: 0  Instance: /foo
# ** Note: Entering S1, waiting for stop
#    Time: 1 ps  Iteration: 1  Instance: /foo
```

In fact, this is the kind of style recommended for register inference.  First assign the new value, then wait for the event.

But since this is a model, we can go one farther.  We can use a `variable` and then we can do a **blocking** assignment.  This blocks execution until the assignment is complete.  For example:

```
main : PROCESS
  variable state : states := S0;
BEGIN
  while true loop
    CASE state IS
         WHEN S0 =>
            report "Entering S0, waiting for start";
            WAIT UNTIL start = '1';
            state := S1;

         WHEN S1 =>
            report "Entering S1, waiting for stop";
            WAIT UNTIL stop = '1';
            state := S2;

         WHEN OTHERS =>
    END CASE;
  end loop;
END PROCESS;
```

Note that I've made `state` a variable, and now use the blocking assignment (`:=`).  And the result:

```
VSIM 1> run 5 ps
# ** Note: Entering S0, waiting for start
#    Time: 0 ps  Iteration: 0  Instance: /foo
# ** Note: Entering S1, waiting for stop
#    Time: 1 ps  Iteration: 1  Instance: /foo
```

Indeed, I can put the assignment before or after the `wait` statement and get the same result.

Your solution to add a `wait for time_value` is problematic.  It introduces a delay where one isn't necessary and perhaps not desirable.  I recommend you change your model to the `variable` based example for more obvious behavior.